# Bootstrapping error in R ( number of columns in matrices)

Tags: r, multiple-columns, statistics-bootstrap

I'm relatively new at R and I'm trying to bootstrap a time splitted morphospace created from an discrete character matrix in R package dispRity.

When I do run the function:

```
  boot_bin_morphospace<-boot.matrix(binned_morphospace, bootstraps = 100)
```

I get the following error-message:

```
 Error in boot.matrix(binned_morphospace, bootstraps = 100) : 
 Some matrices in data have different number of columns.
```

I checked the matrices via:

```
 str(binned_morphospace)
```

and I get the following output:

```
 List of 3
$ data    :List of 14
..$ 262-261:List of 7

.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
..$ 261-260:List of 9
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
..$ 260-259:List of 13
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
..$ 259-258:List of 13
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
..$ 258-257:List of 13
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
..$ 257-256:List of 16
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
..$ 256-255:List of 17
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 255-254:List of 23
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 254-253:List of 24
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 253-252:List of 35
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 252-251:List of 37
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 251-250:List of 37
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 250-249:List of 37
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
..$ 249-248:List of 37
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "0" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "1" "0" "0" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
.. ..$   : chr [1:136] "?" "?" "?" "1" ...
 $ elements: chr [1:43] 
 $ series  : chr [1:15] "discrete" "262-261" "261-260" "260-259" ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "dispRity"
```

To me it looks like all 14 metrices do have the same numer of colums (136).

I've gone through all of the resources I could find and can't seem to find out whats wrong or how to make it work...

Can someone help me and/or tell me what exactly the error refers to ?

Thanks !!!  H.